# If else condition error in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I write a simple django condition but it not working

```
{% if request.user == "sami"  %}
sami
{% else %}
khan
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `request.user` is an instance of the user model (or an Anonymous user instance for users that haven't logged in) you want to check either `request.user.username`, `request.user.first_name` or `request.user.last_name`

Comment: Try outputting ```{{ request.user }}``` what does it output?

Comment: *"it not working"* is not a good error description. Please add more details like the full error traceback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Requset.user*** is an object.
You need to write
`{% if request.user.username == "sami"  %}`
or
`{% if request.user.name == "sami"  %}`  whatever is in your model